# Wordpress - Pagination on Custom Template not showing (Lollum Framework - Lotusflower Theme)

Tags: wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've been working with a wordpress theme named Lotusflower.
I have created a page template (copy pasted the index.php) and used a WP_Query to get the posts i desire to show on this page.
However, the themes inbuilt pagination function does not seem to work here.
Could you please explain why?

```
//Query for the posts
<?php
/**
 * Lollum
 * 
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme and one of the
 * two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Lollum Themes
 * @author Lollum <support@lollum.com>
 *
 */
/*
Template Name: What's New
*/
$postsPerPage = 3;
$page = 1;
$post_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $page,
    'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage
)); ?>
```

Then i use it like this to fetch the latest posts on my custom page template:

```
<?php // START the loop 
?>
<?php while ($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php #CUSTOM ADDITIONS : SHOW VIEWS echo wpb_get_post_views(get_the_ID()); 
?>

<?php get_template_part('content/content', get_post_format()); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php // END the loop 
?>

<?php lollum_pagination(); ?>

<?php // lollum_pagination_default(); 
?>

</div>
```

where as the lollum_pagination() function looks like this:

```
    /**
 * Pagination
 */
if (!function_exists('lollum_pagination')) {
    function lollum_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) {  
        $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  
        global $paged;
        if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;
        if($pages == '') {
            global $wp_query;
            $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
            if(!$pages) {
                $pages = 1;
            }
        }   
        if(1 != $pages) {
            echo "<nav class='pagination'>";
            echo "<h2 class='assistive-text'>" . __('Post navigation', 'lollum') . "</h2>";
            if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($paged - 1) . "'>&laquo;</a>";

            for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
                if (1 != $pages &&(!($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems)) {
                    echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>" . $i . "</span>":"<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($i) . "' class='inactive' >" . $i . "</a>";
                }
            }
            if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($paged + 1) . "'>&raquo;</a>";  
            echo "</nav>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I did not fiddle around in this function. I have a guess it doesnt work because i need to use another way to query the posts? That would be my guess.
On my index.php (where i copied the code from) the exact same piece of code works perfectly (there i did not use the custom array because it queries the posts directly i guess)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing the following:

1. Change the name of $post_query to $wp_query (because the function uses this name)
2. use     'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ), instead of an integer $page. for custom queries it seems you need to use query var.

This solved it.